# Render a Div in specific version of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

I have an application which I am intentionally rendering in IE7 but want a div render in IE9 version if the browser is IE8+.

Is there any way to do it?

Reason to render application in IE 7 is because my client is using XP as well.

Please help ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use IE's conditional comments:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

In your case:

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<div>Your div</div>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "CSS HACK" to distinguish different versions of IE. There are some ways to do it.
1. conditional comment

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>this only works in IE8+<![endif]-->
```

2.prefix

```
.hack{background:#000\0;}/*works only in IE8+*/
```

3.@media

```
@media screen\0 {body { background: green; }}/*works in IE8+*/
```

for more details, you can look up in :
http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt